# PageIndexChanging programmatically Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to dynamically create the event `PageIndexChanging` in the backend part of the page like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gw = new GridView();
        gw.ID = "gwGroupPeopleByCity";
        gw.PageSize = 20;
        gw.AllowPaging = true;
        gw.AllowSorting = true;
        gw.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gw.PageIndexChanging += ...;
...
}
```

And the firm should be like:

```
protected void gwGroupPeopleByCity_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{ ... }
```

But when i try to put `gwGroupPeopleByCity_PageIndexChanging` in the `PageIndexChanging` property it gives me an error. Moreover, it says that `gw` is out of scope (clearly). How can i fix those? Thanks everybody.

Comment: You say that you put gwGroupPeopleByCity_PageIndexChanging in PageIndexChanging property. So you have GridView in aspx file ? If yes that why you create GridView gw in code behind ?

Comment: No, sorry, i have only 2 content holder and 1 panel in the aspx, where i put the generated gview. I need to call the pageindexchanging method in the page_load using gw.PageIndexChanging... and something else that i miss.

Comment: Are you recreating the GridView on postback? Are you using `Page.FindControl("gwGroupPeopleByCity")` to initialize `gw` in your `PageIndexChanging` method?

Comment: Yes, because i do the code in the `page_load` method, and after that part, i go for this check:
`if (!Page.IsPostBack || Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains(gw.ID))
{
     BindData(gw);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this inside the PageIndexChanging event?

```
var gw = sender as GridView;
```

Comment: I can't try it because i don't know how to call the method...
This gives me an error for example:
`gw.PageIndexChanging += gwGroupPeopleByCity_PageIndexChanging(...);` but to be honest, i miss which params i need in the call. If it was a static gridview on the aspx page, i would have no problem to act, but the method in that case is standard and created with Visual Studio.

Comment: @J_J why you want to call gwGroupPeopleByCity_PageIndexChanging on your own ? PageIndexChanging  should be raised automatically when you changing page index of the grid view control.

Comment: Then how can i manage the method if it's not bound to the gridview? Because i don't have the gridview in aspx page when the compiler starts working. I have the c# code to create it.